# Mongo upgrade script issue - Not able to connect DB

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I am working on a MongoDB upgrade script using the shell script version with the help of the below reference.

https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh

However, I am not able to connect to the mongo server instance.

**Error**

```
error: mongod does not appear to have stayed running -- perhaps it had an error?
```

**Script**

Below is sample code snippet

```
 if [ -n "$shouldPerformInitdb" ]; then
        mongodHackedArgs=( "$@" )
        if _parse_config "$@"; then
            _mongod_hack_ensure_arg_val --config "$tempConfigFile" "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        fi
        _mongod_hack_ensure_arg_val --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        _mongod_hack_ensure_arg_val --port 27017 "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        _mongod_hack_ensure_no_arg --bind_ip_all "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        
        # remove "--auth" and "--replSet" for our initial startup (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#start-mongodb-without-access-control)
        # https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/211
        _mongod_hack_ensure_no_arg --auth "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        if [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" ] && [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            _mongod_hack_ensure_no_arg_val --replSet "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        fi
        
        # "BadValue: need sslPEMKeyFile when SSL is enabled" vs "BadValue: need to enable SSL via the sslMode flag when using SSL configuration parameters"
        tlsMode='disabled'
        if _mongod_hack_have_arg '--tlsCertificateKeyFile' "$@"; then
            tlsMode='allowTLS'
            elif _mongod_hack_have_arg '--sslPEMKeyFile' "$@"; then
            tlsMode='allowSSL'
        fi
        # 4.2 switched all configuration/flag names from "SSL" to "TLS"
        if [ "$tlsMode" = 'allowTLS' ] || mongod --help 2>&1 | grep -q -- ' --tlsMode '; then
            _mongod_hack_ensure_arg_val --tlsMode "$tlsMode" "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        else
            _mongod_hack_ensure_arg_val --sslMode "$tlsMode" "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        fi
        
        if stat "/proc/$$/fd/1" > /dev/null && [ -w "/proc/$$/fd/1" ]; then
            # https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/38c0eb538d0fd390c6cb9ce9ae9894153f6e8ef5/src/mongo/db/initialize_server_global_state.cpp#L237-L251
            # https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/164#issuecomment-293965668
            _mongod_hack_ensure_arg_val --logpath "/proc/$$/fd/1" "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        else
            initdbLogPath="$(_dbPath "$@")/docker-initdb.log"
            echo >&2 "warning: initdb logs cannot write to '/proc/$$/fd/1', so they are in '$initdbLogPath' instead"
            _mongod_hack_ensure_arg_val --logpath "$initdbLogPath" "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        fi
        _mongod_hack_ensure_arg --logappend "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        
        pidfile="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid"
        rm -f "$pidfile"
        _mongod_hack_ensure_arg_val --pidfilepath "$pidfile" "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
        
        "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}" --fork
        
        mongo=( mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --quiet )
        
        # check to see that our "mongod" actually did start up (catches "--help", "--version", MongoDB 3.2 being silly, slow prealloc, etc)
        # https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16292
        tries=30
        while true; do
            if ! { [ -s "$pidfile" ] && ps "$(< "$pidfile")" &> /dev/null; }; then
                # bail ASAP if "mongod" isn't even running
                echo >&2
                echo >&2 "error: $originalArgOne does not appear to have stayed running -- perhaps it had an error?"
                echo >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            if "${mongo[@]}" 'admin' --eval 'quit(0)' &> /dev/null; then
                # success!
                break
            fi
            (( tries-- ))
            if [ "$tries" -le 0 ]; then
                echo >&2
                echo >&2 "error: $originalArgOne does not appear to have accepted connections quickly enough -- perhaps it had an error?"
                echo >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            sleep 1
        done
        
        if [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" ] && [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            rootAuthDatabase='admin'
            
            "${mongo[@]}" "$rootAuthDatabase" <<-EOJS
                db.createUser({
                    user: $(_js_escape "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME"),
                    pwd: $(_js_escape "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD"),
                    roles: [ { role: 'root', db: $(_js_escape "$rootAuthDatabase") } ]
                })
            EOJS
        fi
        
        export MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE="${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE:-test}"
        
        fixVersionFile="/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fixVersions.js"  # this file executes the admin db metadata for feature compatability
        echo
        for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
            log "Run entrypoint $f"
            case "$f" in
                *.sh) echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
                *.js) echo "$0: running $f"; "${mongo[@]}" "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" "$f"; echo ;;
                *)    echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
            esac
            echo
        done
        
        "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}" --shutdown
        rm -f "$pidfile"
        
        echo
        echo 'MongoDB init process complete; ready for start up.'
        echo
    fi
    
    # MongoDB 3.6+ defaults to localhost-only binding
    haveBindIp=
    if _mongod_hack_have_arg --bind_ip "$@" || _mongod_hack_have_arg --bind_ip_all "$@"; then
        haveBindIp=1
        elif _parse_config "$@" && jq --exit-status '.net.bindIp // .net.bindIpAll' "$jsonConfigFile" > /dev/null; then
        haveBindIp=1
    fi
    if [ -z "$haveBindIp" ]; then
        # so if no "--bind_ip" is specified, let's add "--bind_ip_all"
        set -- "$@" --bind_ip_all
    fi
    
    unset "${!MONGO_INITDB_@}"
fi
```

Any views or help ?

Comment: You may consider [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works) for such tasks.